# Assigning method to object at runtime in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to do the Javascript equivalent in Python:

```
a.new_func = function(arg1, arg2) {
    var diff = arg1 - arg2;
    return diff * diff;
}
```

Right now, the way I'm doing this is by defining the method first, and then assigning it, but my question is whether or not Python allows a shorthand to do the assigning and the defining part in the same line.  Something like this:

```
a.new_func = def new_func(arg1, arg2):
    diff = arg1 - arg2
    return diff * diff
```

Instead of this:

```
def new_func(arg1, arg2):
    diff = arg1 - arg2
    return diff * diff
a.new_func = new_func
```

I realize the difference is not major, but am still interested to know whether or not it's possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python supports no such syntax.

I suppose if you wanted, you could write a decorator. It might look a bit nicer:

```
def method_of(instance):
    def method_adder(function):
        setattr(instance, function.__name__, function)
        return function
    return method_adder

@method_of(a)
def new_func(arg1, arg2):
    stuff()
```

Or if you want the method to have access to `self`:

```
def method_of(instance):
    def method_adder(function):
        setattr(instance, function.__name__, function.__get__(instance))
        return function
    return method_adder

@method_of(a)
def new_func(self, arg1, arg2):
    stuff()
```

Comment: This actually turned out much neater than I expected. If I ever need to dynamically add methods to objects, I'll probably use a decorator. I wonder how many times this has been reinvented.

Answer (score 6):

The closest thing to what you're looking for are lambda expressions, which are not as easy to use as properly written functions:

```
a.new_function = lambda arg1,arg2 : (arg1-arg2)**2
```

However, in almost all cases, defining a function, and assigning it, the way you have done in your example is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

You should notice that an instance method is not a lambda.

For instance, lets do a simple experiment in IPython

```
In [12]: class A:
   ....:     def f(self):
   ....:         return 1
   ....:     

In [13]: A.f.__class__
Out[13]: instancemethod

In [14]: another_f = lambda self: 1

In [15]: another_f.__class__
Out[15]: function
```

Trying to bind an attribute to a `lambda` will fail miserably when calling it.

```
In [27]: an_instance = A()

In [28]: an_instance.g = lambda self: 2

In [29]: an_instance.g()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-5122c91d3e8f> in <module>()
----> 1 an_instance.g()

TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

What you should do, instead, is wrapping the lambda with `types.MethodType`

```
In [31]: an_instance.g = types.MethodType(lambda self: 2, an_instance)

In [32]: an_instance.g()
Out[32]: 2
```

There is some weird magic happening behind called `descriptors`. In my opinion, this is not a quite OO solution, but... Well, if you want to know more about it, here is a link http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html

Answer (score 0):

So I am assuming you want to know that how to define the function runtime.

May be something similar in the link
[create function dynamically](http://snipplr.com/view/17819/)