# Are __dict__ and __weakref__ the default slots at class definition?

Tags: python, class, instance, python-internals, slots

According to the [Python language documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots):

> `__slots__` allow us to explicitly declare data members (like properties) and deny the creation of `__dict__` and `__weakref__` (unless explicitly declared in `__slots__` or available in a parent.)

So I am wondering if this class

```py
>>> class A: __slots__ = ('__dict__', '__weakref__')
... 
>>> del A.__slots__
>>> vars(A)
mappingproxy({
    '__module__': '__main__',
    '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>,
    '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>,
    '__doc__': None
})
```

is equivalent to this one:

```py
>>> class A: pass
... 
>>> vars(A)
mappingproxy({
    '__module__': '__main__',
    '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>,
    '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>,
    '__doc__': None
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don’t set a `__slots__` attribute, the default is to create the `__weakref__` and `__dict__` slots in certain conditions.

This happens in `type.__new__()`; a class is given descriptors to access memory slots for each instance:

- First, a check is made if the type *can* have these slots by testing for the [`tp_dictoffset`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_dictoffset), [`tp_weaklistoffset`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_weaklistoffset) and [`tp_itemsize`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_itemsize) values in the type object struct.

  - You can only have a `__dict__` slot if the base class doesn’t already define one (`base->tp_dictoffset` is 0).
  - You can only have a `__weakref__` slot if the base type doesn’t define one (`base->tp_weaklistoffset` is 0) and the base has fixed-length instances (`base->tp_itemsize` is 0).
- Then, if there is no `__slots__`, flag variables are set to actually enable the slots being added.

The [`type.__new__()` implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/76d270ec2b776cc5331935cc58c2d63622f1c0e9/Objects/typeobject.c#L2375-L2862) is long, but the relevant section looks like this:

```c
    slots = _PyDict_GetItemIdWithError(dict, &PyId___slots__);
    nslots = 0;
    add_dict = 0;
    add_weak = 0;
    may_add_dict = base->tp_dictoffset == 0;
    may_add_weak = base->tp_weaklistoffset == 0 && base->tp_itemsize == 0;
    if (slots == NULL) {
        if (PyErr_Occurred()) {
            goto error;
        }
        if (may_add_dict) {
            add_dict++;
        }
        if (may_add_weak) {
            add_weak++;
        }
    }
    else {
        /* Have slots */
        ...
    }
```

Then, some 400 lines lower down, you'll find the code that actually creates the slots:

```c
    if (add_dict) {
        if (base->tp_itemsize)
            type->tp_dictoffset = -(long)sizeof(PyObject *);
        else
            type->tp_dictoffset = slotoffset;
        slotoffset += sizeof(PyObject *);
    }
    if (add_weak) {
        assert(!base->tp_itemsize);
        type->tp_weaklistoffset = slotoffset;
        slotoffset += sizeof(PyObject *);
    }
```

When extending certain native types (such as `int` or `bytes`) you don’t get a `__weakref__` slot as they have variable-length instances (handled by `tp_itemsize`).

Comment: Thanks a lot. “For Python classes, this is always the case” Except for subclasses of a *variable-length* type (like the built-in types `int`, `tuple`, and `bytes`) since they have a non zero `__itemsize__` attribute and therefore they will not get a `__weakref__` attribute, right?

Comment: @Maggyero right, it depends on the type of the base. I should have been clearer.

Comment: Nice edit. About the terminology, when we say “slots”, are we talking about the descriptors on the class or the reserved storage on each class instance referenced by the descriptors, or both?

Comment: @Maggyero the reserved storage. The descriptors are the bridge between that memory and Python code.

Comment: The [Descriptor HowTo](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#member-objects-and-slots) seems to confirm that slots are the reserved storage on class *instances* like you said: “When a class defines `__slots__`, it replaces instance dictionaries with a fixed-length array of slot values.” and “The `object.__new__()` method takes care of creating instances that have slots instead of an instance dictionary.”

Comment: Yet in your answer you said: “remember, these slots live on the class object, they are descriptors” and “you'll find the code that actually creates the slots” and `type->tp_dictoffset = slotoffset;` and `type->tp_weaklistoffset = slotoffset;`. This seems to contradict that slots live on the class *instance* since, as I understand it, the code you are referring to creates a class with the relevant data descriptors (`__dict__`, `__weakref__`, or members listed in `__slots__`), not a class instance with the relevant reserved slots. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Maggyero: sorry, that can indeed be confusing. The class structure has to track what the instance structure will look like, so the class tracks the offsets.