# How to create read-only slots?

Tags: python, super, slots, readonly-attribute

Slots are *writable* by default:

```py
>>> class A: __slots__ = ('x',)
... 
>>> list(vars(A))
['__module__', '__slots__', 'x', '__doc__']
>>> vars(A)['x']
<member 'x' of 'A' objects>
>>> a = A()
>>> a.x = 'foo'
>>> del a.x
```

How to create *read-only* slots, like the slots `'__thisclass__'` , `'__self__'`, and `'__self_class__'` of the class `super`?

```py
>>> list(vars(super))
['__repr__', '__getattribute__', '__get__', '__init__', '__new__',
 '__thisclass__', '__self__', '__self_class__', '__doc__']
>>> vars(super)['__thisclass__']
<member '__thisclass__' of 'super' objects>
>>> s = super(int, 123)
>>> s.__thisclass__ = float
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: readonly attribute
>>> del s.__thisclass__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: readonly attribute
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, there is no option from Python code to create read-only descriptors like the ones used for `__thisclass__`, etc.

In the C API, slots all use the same descriptor object type, which become read-only for entries in [`PyMemberDef` arrays](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html?highlight=pymemberdef#c.PyMemberDef) that have `flags` set to `READONLY`.

E.g. the `super` descriptors you identified are defined in the [`super_members` array](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/76d270ec2b776cc5331935cc58c2d63622f1c0e9/Objects/typeobject.c#L7858-L7866):

```c
static PyMemberDef super_members[] = {
    {"__thisclass__", T_OBJECT, offsetof(superobject, type), READONLY,
     "the class invoking super()"},
    {"__self__",  T_OBJECT, offsetof(superobject, obj), READONLY,
     "the instance invoking super(); may be None"},
    {"__self_class__", T_OBJECT, offsetof(superobject, obj_type), READONLY,
     "the type of the instance invoking super(); may be None"},
    {0}
};
```

When `__slots__` is being processed, there is no path where you can set this flag; the [code in `type.__new__` just sets the first three values](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/76d270ec2b776cc5331935cc58c2d63622f1c0e9/Objects/typeobject.c#L2761-L2776), which are `name`, `type` and `offset`, respectively:

```c
    mp = PyHeapType_GET_MEMBERS(et);
    slotoffset = base->tp_basicsize;
    if (et->ht_slots != NULL) {
        for (i = 0; i < nslots; i++, mp++) {
            mp->name = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(
                PyTuple_GET_ITEM(et->ht_slots, i));
            if (mp->name == NULL)
                goto error;
            mp->type = T_OBJECT_EX;
            mp->offset = slotoffset;


            /* __dict__ and __weakref__ are already filtered out */
            assert(strcmp(mp->name, "__dict__") != 0);
            assert(strcmp(mp->name, "__weakref__") != 0);


            slotoffset += sizeof(PyObject *);
        }
    }
```

For reference:

- `PyHeapType_GET_MEMBERS` accesses the `PyMemberDef` array for the new type object being created. It has the right number of slots allocated already.
- `et->ht_slots` is the tuple of slot names.
- `slotoffset` is the relative offset into the instance object memory area to store the slot contents.
- the `T_OBJECT_EX` value for the `type` field means the slot stores a pointer to a Python object, and if the pointer is set to `NULL` an `AttributeError` is raised when you try to get the value.

Note that if it *was* possible to set these slots to read-only, you'd also need a mechanism to provide their value *before* creating a new instance! After all, if all Python code was prevented from setting a readonly attribute on instances, how would your Python class ever get to set the initial value?