# Why is __get__() specified to have an optional third argument?

Tags: python, python-descriptors

The [Descriptor HowTo Guide (Descriptor protocol)](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol) specifies that `__get__()` must be callable with 2 and 3 arguments:

```
descr.__get__(self, obj, type=None) -> value
```

Why has it been defined like this? AFAIK CPython will always call this method with 3 arguments, so that `None` default argument is never used.

I have seen [Why do people default owner parameter to None in __get__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626653/why-do-people-default-owner-parameter-to-none-in-get), but that asks a different question, i.e. why people write their descriptors with that signature, not why the signature has been defined to be like this, and none of the current answers go into why it has been specified like this.

Comment: @jonrsharpe None of the answers in that dupe target appear to answer this question. This question is about why the third argument is "optional", not about what it means in general. The OP is asking in what scenario you'll get `owner=None`

Comment: Voting to reopen

Comment: The docs for `object.__get__()` say: "PEP 252 specifies that __get__() is callable with one or two arguments. Python’s own built-in descriptors support this specification; however, it is likely that some third-party tools have descriptors that require both arguments. Python’s own __getattribute__() implementation always passes in both arguments whether they are required or not."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've personally never written a descriptor with a `None` default - and I had not notcied to this day it was specified as optional.

However, the text in the [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__) contains what I think you want as an answer:

> PEP 252 specifies that `__get__()` is callable with one or two
> arguments. Python’s own built-in descriptors support this
> specification; however, it is likely that some third-party tools have
> descriptors that require both arguments. Python’s own
> `__getattribute__()` implementation always passes in both arguments whether they are required or not.

So, although PEP 252 specifies the 3rd argument as optional, the language itself will always fill in both `instance` and `owner` parameters, and few people care, when writing descriptors, for an eventual possible manually written call to  `__get__` which might ommit the owner. And, on the other hand, people who specify the default `None` to `owner` will do so because the docs, as you've noted, say that it should be optional.

Comment: I don't think that paragraph really answers my question, it only says that Python follows the specification from PEP 252 and PEP 252 also does not give a reasoning. My question was about _why_ it has been specified like that. But I think this is the best I can get, counting it as "there is no answer or explanation".